# QListView external drop doesn't work

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qlistview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm trying to implement drag&drop items (plain/text) from one QListView to another. The dragging starts well (I even able to drop items to another applications that accept text drops), but my second QListView doesn't accept drops for some reason.
Here is how the list view configured:

```
ui->lessonsListView->setAcceptDrops(true);
ui->lessonsListView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
ui->lessonsListView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DropOnly);
ui->lessonsListView->setDragDropOverwriteMode(true);
```

The proxy model for this listView implements the next methods:

```
Qt::ItemFlags LessonsProxyModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | QSortFilterProxyModel::flags(index);
}

Qt::DropActions LessonsProxyModel::supportedDropActions() const
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}

bool LessonsProxyModel::canDropMimeData(const QMimeData *data,
    Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    Q_UNUSED(action);
    Q_UNUSED(row);
    Q_UNUSED(column);

    if (!data->hasFormat("text/plain") || !parent.isValid())
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool LessonsProxyModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data,
    Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    if (!canDropMimeData(data, action, row, column, parent))
        return false;

    emit dataDropped(data, parent);

    return true;
}
```

From the application output I see that only `supportedDropActions()` and `flags()` are called. Neither `canDropMimeData()` nor `dropMimeData()` ever called. What am I doing wrong? 
Any hints will be appreciated.

Thank you!

**EDITED:**

Just in case: below is source code for listView and model from those drag is initiated:
listView setup:

```
ui->abonsListView->setDragEnabled(true);
```

proxyModel code:

```
Qt::ItemFlags AbonsProxyModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | QSortFilterProxyModel::flags(index);
}

Qt::DropActions AbonsProxyModel::supportedDragActions() const
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}

QStringList AbonsProxyModel::mimeTypes() const
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    QStringList types;
    types << "text/plain";
    return types;
}

QMimeData *AbonsProxyModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData();

    foreach (const QModelIndex &index, indexes)
        if (index.isValid())
        {
            mimeData->setText(data(index, AbonsModel::Id).toString());
            qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
            return mimeData;
        }

    return mimeData;
}
```

Comment: I do believe, you must override `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent` and `dropEvent` of the `QListView` subclass. Have a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) and [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-draganddrop.html)

Comment: Thanks! I will try. But the above documentation states: `This document describes the basic drag and drop mechanism and outlines the approach used to enable it in custom controls.` And I just followed the instructions under the `Using drag and drop with item views` link. Also dragging work perfect for another list view without any subclassing: item views already have support for drag and drop.

Comment: Yes the drag is perfectly implemented. However the drop does not work as expected. I have tried to do a simple drag and drop experiment with a `QListView` coupled with `QFileSystemModel` and a file browser (dolphin). The drag from `QListView` to dolphin works marvelously, but the other way round is not accepted. So I believe, you will have to set up `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent` and `dropEvent` for the widget where you are going to perform the drop.

Comment: Drop to `QListView` works fine, you don't need any subclasses. Show code, where you configures `QListView`, that started drag.

Comment: I've posted "drag side's" code. BTW digging into Qt sources I found out, that functions like `canDropMimeData()` are not declared `virtual` in the `QAbstractProxyModel` and because of this wrong function is called: `QAbstractProxyModel::canDropMimeData()` instead of my model's `canDropMimeData()`. It seems like this is the reason, but I don't know how to fix or work around it... Seems like it works only with `QAbstractItemModel`.

Comment: BTW my Qt version is 5.5.1. The documentation for `QAbstractProxyModel` says: `virtual bool canDropMimeData(const QMimeData * data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent) const` but in the `qabstractproxymodel.h` I see `bool canDropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;`. Have I missed something?

Comment: I believe the confusion is because of `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE`. This is a `C++11` special. `C++11` introduced a  preprocessor macro. It's basically to check if you are really overriding a member or not. 

For example, if you want to override `void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* )` and you end up typing `void painterEvent( QPaintEvent )`, your function is never called. 

If you add void `painterEvent( QPaintEvent ) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` a compile time check is preformed and the compiler tell you there is no such function defined which you are trying to override, thus saving tons of headache and lots of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found an answer! When I started writing this code I copypasted some pieces from Qt docs [Using Drag and Drop with Item Views](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views) and in this article they just missed `const` specifier for reimplementation of `canDropMimeData()`. Hence my version of `canDropMimeData()` became non-virtual and QListView just called the method from base class `QAbstractProxyModel`. I've added `const` - and all is working like a charm without any subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

I have not much experience with proxy models. Going through the docs, I think I have an rough idea of what these two functions are. These functions do not get called automatically. You have to "call" them from your view.

Firstly, checking if you have the right data is the model's work. So these are two convenience functions in the model to ease your work. These are model specific functions and not generic functions and hence are never defined for an abstract model.

Consider this scenario. From somewhere a `QMimeData` object is dropped into your view. How do you know if this data is of the right type? Whose work is it to decide if the data is of the right type?

In the `Model-View` framework, `View` does only painting work. It's upto the `Model` to decide things like how to process the data, what to show, what is acceptable and what is not. So when a piece of data is dropped on the `View` you need to send it to the `Model` to check if the dropped data satisfies the `Model`'s requirement. The hook to do this work is `bool Model::canDropMimeData(...)`.

If it is acceptable, then the processing of the data will also need to be done by the `Model` itself. Again you need to send the data to the `Model`. The hook for this is `bool Model::dropMimeData(...)`.

How do you know if the data was processed successfully? Check return value! If the data was processes successfully, then you most probably need to update your `View`.

So in addition to the code you have above, you **MUST** override the `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent` and `dropEvent` of the receiving `View` so that you can call `canDropMimeData(...)` and `dropMimeData(...)`

```
/* You need to allow the drag to enter the widget/view. */
/* This is a must. */
void TargetView::dragEnterEvent( QDragEnterEvent *deEvent ) {

    deEvent->acceptProposedAction();
};

/* This is optional. Use this to check if the data can be */
/* dropped at the current mouse position. Example: In a */
/* FileSystem View, it makes no sense to drop a bunch of */
/* files on top of a file, but makes sense it you drop it */
/* in an empty space or on a folder */
void TargetView::dragMoveEvent( QDragMoveEvent *dmEvent ) {
    /* You can do something like this */
    if ( indexAt( dmEvent->pos() ).isValid() ) {
        /* You cannot drop it on an existing index */
        /* If you ignore it, the cursor changes to */
        /* 'don't drop' image */
        dmEvent->ignore();
    }

    else {
        /* Empty space. Tell the user to feel free */
        /* to perform the drop. We accept the event */
        /* Cursor shows the drag+drop icon */
        dmEvent->accept();
    }
};

void TargetView::dropEvent( QDropEvent *dpEvent ) {
    /* Here is where you call canDropMimeData and dropMimeData */
    QMimeData *mData = dpEvent->mimeData();
    if ( model->canDropMimeData( mData, ..., ..., ..., ... ) ) {
        /* Add the data to the model */
        bool updated = model->dropMimeData( mData, ..., ..., ..., ... );
        if ( updated ) {
            /* Intimate the view to update itself */
            update();
        }
    }
};
```